# how to do error handling with using statements in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, transactions, error-handling, using-statement

im trying to do delete records from multiple database tables. For error handling i'm using a try/catch block as seen beneath.

```
try
{
    using (SqlCeConnection oConn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        oConn.Open();
        using (SqlCeTransaction transaction = oConn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            //delete from multiple tables using ADO.NET
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
catch
{
   //error handling
}
```

problem is when an exception is raised the transaction is not rolled back. When reading multiple forums my conclusion is that 'using' statements should dispose the transaction and the connection. When disposed, the uncommitted transaction should be rolled back.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Move your `try-catch` block inside of `using`

Comment: @L.B That shouldn't make a difference so long as the exception occurs before the commit line.  On the surface the code looks fine, but it depends on how the disposal code is implemented in the SqlCe DLLs as to what it does, I can only assume it does the common sense thing and rolls back the transaction.

Comment: I hate to sound stupid, but... how do you know that your transaction is getting committed despite never hitting transaction.Commit?

Comment: You can not  use `oConn` for rollback outside of `using`

Comment: The dispose of the SqlTransaction works as you think (with the rollback) and will **always** be called when wrapped in a using. What you are describing should not be happening unless the exception happens after the commit. Are you sure that isn't the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you're not setting the `Transaction` property of your `SqlCeCommand` (which you don't show).

```
try
{
    using (SqlCeConnection oConn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        oConn.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand command = oConn.CreateCommand())
        {
            using (SqlCeTransaction transaction = oConn.BeginTransaction())
            {
               command.Transaction = transaction;
               //delete from multiple tables using ADO.NET using command
               transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

    }
}
catch
{
   //error handling
}
```

The `SqlCeCommand` won't automatically enlist in the transaction, you have to set it explicitly. As far as I'm aware, the `Dispose()` of the `Transaction` should roll it back, but you can call `Rollback()` yourself as others suggest just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
try 
{
  using (SqlCeConnection oConn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
  {
    oConn.Open();

    using (SqlCeTransaction transaction = oConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
          //delete from multiple tables using ADO.NET
          transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch 
        {
           transaction.Rollback();
           throw;
        }
    }
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  // do Exception handling here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To play it safe:

```
    using (SqlCeTransaction transaction = oConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
          //delete from multiple tables using ADO.NET
          transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
           transaction.Rollback();
           throw;
        }
    }
```

I couldn't find a direct piece of documentation that states a transaction is rolled back by default.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `try{...} catch{}` block is in the wrong place. It should be within the using statement, preferably around the `transaction.Commit`